# Over writing a dataframe with a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose a dict like

```
rows = [{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":2},{"A":3, "B":2}]
```

A dataframe `df` may or may not contain `A` and `B` columns, in either case I want to concat or update its corresponding values.

My solution is:

```
data = rows[0]

for key,val in data.items():
    if key in df:
       df.drop(key, axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

I would like to know if it is correct and safe or if there are better ways.

Suppose `df` is:

```
   A  C
   10 4
   10 4
   10 4
```

After update with `rows` it should be:

```
   A   B   C
   1   2   4
   2   2   4
   3   2   4
```

In other words the data frame is over written with new values. Maybe [combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine) function is useful, however it wants a function.

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, rows isn't a dictionary here.

Comment: @Mortz Not yet....

Comment: Perhaps you could show the desired output from your code?

Comment: @BlackRaven I did ... However, my solution seems working

Comment: hi @Ahmad, I've updated my solution, please see if it could meet your requirement :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to merge the 2 DataFrame to fill in the missing column?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":3}])
dfA = df1.drop("B", axis=1)

print(pd.concat([df1, dfA], axis=1))
   A  B  A
0  1  2  1
1  3  2  3
2  4  3  4

print(pd.merge(df1, dfA, on="A", how="left"))
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  2
2  4  3
```

**Edit:** So you are looking to update the old dataframe with new columns in the new dataframe. Here's a possible solution:

I've defined a function to take in both old and new dataframes. Then I check for new columns that exists in the old dataframe and drop them, so that these new columns can be concatenated to the remaining columns.

```
import pandas as pd

def update_dataframe(old_df, new_df):
    for col in new_df.columns:
        if col in old_df.columns:  #drop the old column
            old_df = old_df.drop(col, axis=1)
    return pd.concat([new_df, old_df], axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame([{"A":10, "C":4},{"A":10, "C":4},{"A":10, "C":4}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":2},{"A":3, "B":2}])
result = update_dataframe(df, df2)
print(result)
```

Output

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  4
1  2  2  4
2  3  2  4
```

**Eidt2:** Yes you can use the `.update()` and `.merge()` methods also. This way is much neater, to include the methods in the new function `update_dataframe2`:

```
def update_dataframe2(old_df, new_df):
    old_df.update(new_df)
    return new_df.merge(old_df)

df = pd.DataFrame([{"A":10, "C":4},{"A":10, "C":4},{"A":10, "C":4}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":2, "B":2},{"A":3, "B":2}])
result = update_dataframe2(df, df2)
print(result)
```

Output is the same as above

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  4
1  2  2  4
2  3  2  4
```

Comment: How about `df.update(df2)` and then `df = df.merge(df2)`

Comment: @Ahmad yes this is a much neater solution!

Answer (score 1):

To update a pandas dataframe you can use the **append** method.
for instance,
dataframe df needs to be updated.

```
rows=([{'A':5,},{'A':0,'B':9},{'A':7,'B':25}]
df=pd.DataFrame(rows)

new_rows=[{"A":1, "B":2},{"A":3, "B":2},{"A":4, "B":3}]

df.append(new_rows,ignore_index=True) # ignore index to reset the numbering
```